# I have custom form loop and the radio value are override

Tags: php, html

I have this on my DB:
[image]

then this is on my backend

```
<?php 
    foreach($form['questions'] as $question) :

        $options = $question['options'];
        $options = explode(',',$options);
?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $question['label']; ?>" name="custom_form[label][]" />
            <label><?php echo $question['label']; ?></label>
            <?php if($question['type'] == 'text'): ?>
                <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $question['label']; ?>" name="custom_form[answer][]" class="form-control" required />
            <?php elseif($question['type'] == 'textarea'): ?>
                <textarea name="custom_form[answer][]" placeholder="<?php echo $question['label']; ?>" class="form-control" required></textarea>
            <?php elseif($question['type'] == 'radio'): ?>

                <div class="input-group btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
                        <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" name="custom_form[answer][]" value="<?php echo $option; ?>" required><?php echo $option; ?></label>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            <?php elseif($question['type'] == 'select'): ?>
                <select class="form-control" name="custom_form[answer][]" required>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php foreach($options as $option): ?>
                        <option><?php echo $option; ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

and this is the result of that PHP, then when I submit it overlap by the new `radio`

before submit

[image]

after submit

[image]

** AS YOU CAN SEE, THE 2nd RADIO IS GONE **

**EDIT** added html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_form[label][]" value="What is your current Immigration status?">
        <label>What is your current Immigration status?</label>
        <select required="" name="custom_form[answer][]" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option>Naturalized Citizen</option>
                .....
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_form[label][]" value="Do you have VISA?">
        <label>Do you have VISA?</label>

        <div data-toggle="buttons" class="input-group btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" required="" value="yes" name="custom_form[answer][]">yes</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" required="" value="no" name="custom_form[answer][]">no</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_form[label][]" value="Which type of VISA do you currently have?">
        <label>Which type of VISA do you currently have?</label>
        <select required="" name="custom_form[answer][]" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option>A-1/A-2</option>
            .....
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom_form[label][]" value="What is your gender?">
        <label>What is your gender?</label>

        <div data-toggle="buttons" class="input-group btn-group">
            <label class="btn btn-default active"><input type="radio" required="" value="male" name="custom_form[answer][]">male</label>
            <label class="btn btn-default"><input type="radio" required="" value="female" name="custom_form[answer][]">female</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT2**

WHEN I USE THIS NOW, I've got `undefined offset` error

```
$custom_forms = $_POST['custom_form'];
foreach($custom_forms['label'] as $key => $question) {
    echo htmlentities($question . ' - ' . $custom_forms['answer'][$key]) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question to ask us?

Comment: HTML? Should we predict?

Comment: @PraveenKumar ok added HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="custom_form[answer][]" />
```

As far as I can see, you are using the same name for your inputs.

Since it is an array it doesnt bother with the text inputs.

But radio buttons work differently, you have 2 groups of radio buttons with the same name, so although the css shows them as two sepparate entities, when you submit the form it will be parsed as only one radio button group.

My solution would be to change the name of the radio inputs to something like

```
"custom_form[answer][input_<?php=$question['id']?>]"
```

Comment: With the modification i proposed You have to change the hidden input for the label too to match the same key.

`<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $question['label']; ?>" name="custom_form[label][]" />` 

change the name for radio labels to `custom_form[label][input_<?php=$question['id']?>]`

You should go and do it for every field now that you are changing that. 
So they are always the same key on the array you get